# Are there any air navigation uses for the HF frequencies?

Tags: navigation

I'm busy revising for a license conversion... Out of curiosity, does anyone know of a radio navigational aid that used the frequencies we call HF (2-25 MHz)?

Comment: What have you found so far? [Gee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gee_%28navigation%29) and [LORAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LORAN) come to mind.

Comment: Hadn't found anything - "UnrecognisedFalling Object" has set me right

Answer (score 7):

Current airborne radionavigation systems use MF (NDB), VHF (VOR/LOC, marker beacons), UHF (G/S), and L-band microwave  (GPS/GNSS, DME) frequencies.  (MLS operates in the C-band, and airborne radar in the X-band, but those are niche applications.)

Historically, the only system that used HF was the UK [Gee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gee_%28navigation%29) system.  [LORAN-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LORAN) had options for the use of HF frequencies, but these were never used, as MF operation just below the 2 MHz mark gave much more consistent results in both reception range and performance, and [LORAN-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loran-C) migrated into the LF band at 180kHz, partially to avoid the difficulties of being co-located with the amateur radio 160m band.  [Decca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decca_Navigator_System) also used LF frequencies, and the [Omega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_(navigation_system)) system operated at VLF to provide (imprecise) global coverage.

Furthermore, the [FCC frequency table](http://www.fcc.gov/oet/spectrum/table/fcctable.pdf) shows no allocations for the Radionavigation service anywhere from 2 to 30MHz, in *any* ITU region.

Answer (score 0):

Comm related - HF frequencies are used for transatlantic/transpac flights out of range of VHF/UHF Comm.